# Why serialization json to byte array is considered better than json to string when exchanging messages via RabbitMQ?

Tags: json, serialization, binary, rabbitmq

It's recommended in another question-answer [RabbitMQ - Send a JSON message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788162/rabbitmq-send-a-json-message/60583488#60583488) to use serialization from object to json to byte array when exchanging messaged via RabbitMQ. I'm reviewing the options to choose the serialization method and not clear what the key benefits of byte array over string are? Why not to serialize from object to json to string? At least it would be easier to trace data in clear through the queues and save on convertion to and from byte array.